# What is the jQuery ajax equivalent to this html-form submit?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

If have a html form like

```
<form method="POST" action="http://.../file.php">
    <input type="text" name="data" id="data" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

I want to make a ajax-request with jQuery, but I don't want to use an invisible form to submit this. But somehow I don't get it to work. My try was

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://.../file.php",
    data: d,
    success: function(msg){
        alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
    }
});
```

were `d`contains a JSON object which I would just paste in the above form field as plaintext. The success function gets executed, but I don't get the answer from the server (which means that something must go wrong :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you POSTing on the same domain? Ajax doesn't work cross-domain.

Comment: damn, that was actually the problem. If I execute both over localhost instead of just opening the html "as file", everything works fine :-)

Answer (score 2):

You just need to create a json object to send through

```
function postData (data) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://.../file.php",
        data: { data: data },
        success: function(msg){
            alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
        }
    });
};

postData("xyz");
```

Or if you wanted to make this more generic you can do

```
function postData (data) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://.../file.php",
        data: data,
        success: function(msg){
            alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
        }
    });
};

postData({input1: "x", input2: "y", input3: "z" });
```

The last one allows you to be more flexible and not have to constantly rewrite the inputs to the AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

`data` must be a set of key/value pairs for the post request to be successful.  You can not specify an arbitrary javascript object, nor can you simply paste in the html from your form as a string.  If `d` is anything other than a key/value pair set, your request will error.

Here's an example of a valid data object:

```
var d = {foo:'bar',fizz:'buzz'};
```

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery Form Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) will help make your code DRY.

```
<html> 
<head> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.form.js"></script> 

    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        // wait for the DOM to be loaded 
        $(document).ready(function() { 
            // bind 'myForm' and provide a simple callback function 
            $('#myForm').ajaxForm(function() { 
                alert("Thank you for your comment!"); 
            }); 
        }); 
    </script> 
</head>
<body>
    <form id="myForm" action="comment.php" method="post"> 
        Name: <input type="text" name="name" /> 
        Comment: <textarea name="comment"></textarea> 
        <input type="submit" value="Submit Comment" /> 
    </form>
</body>
```

More options available at [their website](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/).